# Почему не работает scrollDirection .horizontal

Tags: ios, swift

Что не так с кодом? Почему он отображает всё вертикально, а не в линию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Create a new window for the window property that
        // comes standard on the AppDelegate class. The UIWindow
        // is where all view controllers and views apper.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        // Set the initial View Controller to our instance of ViewController
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainController())
        //
        // Present the window
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift

```
    import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let customCellIdentifier = "customCellIdentifier"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        return customCell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
}


class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .gray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class MainController: CustomCollectionViewController {
    init() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0)
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: По 3 ячейкам судить нельзя, добавте 10. Скрол начнет работать после того как вы заполните UIView рабочую зону.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин, а как тогда вот такая штука работает? я пытаюсь сделать, что-то похожее: https://medium.com/@superpeteblaze/ios-scaling-carousel-component-in-swift-8f263b1e391

Comment: Используйте contentInsets вашего CollectionView, ограничте его сверху и снизу, либо установите фрейм CollectionView поменьше.